# How do you get the selected directory path from file system access api window.showDirectoryPicker()

Tags: javascript, html, web, file-system-access-api

When I choose a folder I do get a dirHandle but cannot figure out what property or method will give me the full path

```
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker()
```

So something like let path = dirHandle.fullpath

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For security reasons the full path will not be revealed to web applications. You can only learn the relative paths by walking through a directory. In the example below, if the user opens `shared/`, you can learn about the existence of `./public` and `./public/file.txt` inside of it, but not that `shared/` lies in `secret/` and further up.

```
/root/secret/shared/public/file.txt
```

Comment: It makes sense. I've also found that with `window.showSaveFilePicker()` I can get the short name of the user-chosen file, but I won't know where it is.

Comment: That's correct. `showSaveFilePicker()` lives up to the same security standards.