# How can I get folder path/directory in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What I am trying to achieve is to open a directory (like "File Explorer" on windows ) and select path to a folder. Not to a file!

I have tried webkitdirectory, directory attribute with type="file" but doesn't work.

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory />
```

Would appreciate to see some simple example how can this be done.

**EDITED:**

I just need to return the path to the folder and not files under the folder.
**Example: C:\Documents\Test**  - this is correct

C:\Documents\Test\someFile.csv - incorrect

[image]

Comment: Out of interest how would you use that information in your app?

Comment: This will be used to show where the user wants to store migrated data. Currently the user has to insert the path manually.

Comment: try this <input  type="file" webkitdirectory = "true" directory/>. Duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Directory Chooser in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Comment: This will upload all files under the folder. But what I want is to get only a path to the folder: https://codepen.io/matuzo/pen/KOdpmq

Comment: This is duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393230/browse-folder-path-in-react

Comment: I found out that this is not possible due to security reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236490/how-do-you-get-the-selected-directory-path-from-file-system-access-api-window-sh