Does window.showSaveFilePicker save a file in the correct place from the end user's standpoint?
Does window.showSaveFilePicker save a file in the correct place from the end user's standpoint?
For security reasons, window.showSaveFilePicker does not show the entire path. That's fine if the end user who is uses the app actually gets their file stored into their desired location on their desktop.
Can anyone with experience with showSaveFilePicker confirm this is the case? If not, what are the alternatives? Eg. What is Gmail using to get me to download attachments into my place of choosing?

"For security reasons, window.showSaveFilePicker does not show the entire path" - what? Of course the user gets to choose the entire path.

Pls see top answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236490/how-do-you-get-the-selected-directory-path-from-file-system-access-api-window-sh

That says "the full path will not be revealed to web applications". It says nothing about what is shown to the user. Have you simply tried it?

Yes i tried it myself and it did not save in the correct place. It saved in the same folder as my .js code as opposed to a different location (eg. C:\Desktop)

Uh this should work. What browser did you use, what code did you run? Try the example code from Kaiido's answer below.

The path isn't accessible to your page's scripts, (why would it need it anyway?), but of course the browser will save the files at the path the user has selected through the OS file picker.
You can just try it yourself (e.g. in your console since stacksnippet's sandbox iframes don't allow tis API), and see if it saved at the expected place:
onclick = async (evt) => {
  const handle = await showSaveFilePicker();
  const writer = await handle.createWritable();
  await writer.write(new Blob(["some content"]));
  await writer.close();
}

